# Feeds not working on my wordpress site

Tags: rss, feedburner

I just made my [wordpress website live finally](http://www.averylawoffice.ca) and now trying to set up the RSS. I came across a couple tutorials saying that you have to go to www.yoursite.com/feed copy the link and place it into the URL area in your feedburner account. However what happens if [nothing shows up](http://www.averylawoffice.ca/feed) when you go to www.yoursite.com/feed ? It says the URL does not exist, however I have a blog on the site.

Is it because my permalinks aren't set to a custom permalink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/feed` slug only works if you've turned on [pretty permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks).  From the looks of things, you haven't.

Instead, you can use this url:

```
http://www.averylawoffice.ca/?feed=rss2
```

Once you turn on pretty permalinks, that URL will *still* work, but the prettyier http://www.averylawoffice.ca/feed will also work.

Comment: Log in to Feedburner and go to the Publicize tab. Then click on Email Subscriptions in the sidebar. Then click Activate to turn them on.